Can you produce chromium(III) nitrate from chromium hydroxide
I am trying to produce chromium(III) nitrate for a catalyst. I read in Fritz Ullmann's Encyclopedia of Industrial Chemistry that:

Chromium(III) oxide hydrate is dissolved in nitric acid and the nitrate is allowed to crystallize.

I presumed the chromium oxide hydrate to be chromium hydroxide but upon reacting the two nothing seemed to occur. Chromium hydroxide should be able to dissolve in a strong acid or base right? I tried making another batch using chromium hydroxide from chromium(III) chloride but this time I didn't wash the sodium ions from the sodium hydroxide I used to convert the chloride into hydroxide and proceeded to react this solution with nitric acid. The solid chromium hydroxide dissolved again but the solution remained a deep blue similar to that of a slightly basic solution of the chromium(III) chloride. I believe that adding the nitric acid brought the pH low enough to re-dissolve the chromium hydroxide but not react. Any advice or idea if this reaction should work?

With sodium ions there are also chloride ions  that make complexes with Cr(III).

Yes my apologies, it may have been superfluous to add that test I tried. The chromium hydroxide without the sodium ions did not react after being dried at a low heat so maybe most of it converted to chromium (iii) oxide even though it only reached about 60C? I need to try one without drying it to see.
